# How to index column based on another column?

Tags: python, pandas

so I am trying to append a column to a data frame that is based on another column in that data frame, where the values directly correspond to the other column. I am having a lot of trouble trying to articulate this well, so I will just demonstrate.

I have the following data frame:

```
           DateTime      Value
--------------------------------
2015-03-11 06:00:00          1
2015-03-11 07:00:00          1
2015-03-11 08:00:00          1
2015-03-11 09:00:00          1
2015-03-11 10:00:00          0
2015-03-11 11:00:00          0
2015-03-11 12:00:00          0
2015-03-11 13:00:00          0
2015-03-11 14:00:00          0
...
```

Now I want to append a column to this data frame that is based on the "Value" column, called "Value_2". I want "Value_2" to display all "1" values, and then find the first instance of "0", display "1" values for 2 more hours (two more rows), and then produce all "0" values onward, like so:

```
DateTime                 Value         Value_2
-----------------------------------------------
2015-03-11 06:00:00          1               1
2015-03-11 07:00:00          1               1
2015-03-11 08:00:00          1               1
2015-03-11 09:00:00          1               1
2015-03-11 10:00:00          0               1
2015-03-11 11:00:00          0               1
2015-03-11 12:00:00          0               0 
2015-03-11 13:00:00          0               0
2015-03-11 14:00:00          0               0
2015-03-11 15:00:00          0               0
...
```

I am trying to produce code so that I can easily change this "tolerance" value of 2 hours to 3 hours, like so:

```
DateTime                 Value         Value_2
-----------------------------------------------
2015-03-11 06:00:00          1               1
2015-03-11 07:00:00          1               1
2015-03-11 08:00:00          1               1
2015-03-11 09:00:00          1               1
2015-03-11 10:00:00          0               1
2015-03-11 11:00:00          0               1
2015-03-11 12:00:00          0               1 
2015-03-11 13:00:00          0               0
2015-03-11 14:00:00          0               0
2015-03-11 15:00:00          0               0
...
```

Or really any number of tolerance hours. And by "tolerance" I just mean how many rows of 0s in the "Value" column can get translated to 1s in the "Value_2" column.

Can this be done in a simple way in python? Or is this actually very complex? I can't wrap my head around what processes and functions this would even need.

Thanks!

Comment: Is your dates in all rows seperated by 1 hour?

Comment: Yes it is. I realize that could complicate things if I did not know if it was all evenly spaced by 1 hour, but in this case, yes, the rows are all separated by 1 hour.

Answer (score 0):

That's pretty straightforward!

I would do this:

```
import pandas as pd

# create a tolerance variable (ie. = 2)
tolerance = 2
# create remaining tolerance to store iteration result
remaining_tolerance = 0

for row, index in df.iterrows():
    # in case df['Value'] is 1
    if index['Value'] == 1:
        df['Value_2'] = 1
        remaining_tolerance = tolerance
    # in case df['Value'] is not 1,
    else:
        # there were a df['Value'] = 1 on the previous 2 (tolerance) rows
        if remaining_tolerance > 0:
            df['Value_2'] = 1
            remaining_tolerance -= 1
        # there were not a df['Value'] = 1 on the previous 2 (tolerance) rows
        else:
            df['Value'] = 0
```

You can control the number of rows that get a value of `1` with the tolerance variable.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the simple function you can use to change the values of tolerance:

```py
def shiftDF(df, tolerance):
  df['Value_2'] = 1
  num = 0
  for i, val in enumerate(list(df['Value'].values)):
    if val == 0 and num == 0:
      df.loc[i+tolerance:, 'Value_2'] = 0
      num = 2

  return df
```

Calling the function:

```
shiftDF(df, 3)

     DateTime          Value Value_2
0   2015-03-11 06:00:00   1   1
1   2015-03-11 07:00:00   1   1
2   2015-03-11 08:00:00   1   1
3   2015-03-11 09:00:00   1   1
4   2015-03-11 10:00:00   0   1
5   2015-03-11 11:00:00   0   1
6   2015-03-11 12:00:00   0   1
7   2015-03-11 13:00:00   0   0
8   2015-03-11 14:00:00   0   0
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use pandas' [Window Operators](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/window.html) (similar to Window Functions in SQL) to compute the rank of the rows based on the `Value` column. Then you can use this information to make the first `num` 0s to 1s.

```py
# Create a new column based on ['Value'] where the next [num] hours are 1
def shiftHours(data, num = 2):
  # Add a new column with the rank by ['Value']
  data['Rank'] = data.groupby('Value').rank()
  data['Value_2'] = data.apply(
      lambda row: int(row['Value'] == 1  # keep the previous 1s
                      or row['Rank'] <= num),  # the next [num] 0s will be one
      axis = 1
    ) 
  # Remove the ['Rank'] temp column
  data = data.drop(columns = ['Rank'])
  return data
```

Let me know if this works for you.

You can sort the DF by `DateTime` to be sure this works as expected. In the function above I am assuming that the data is already sorted.